# How can I receive phone touch in a C# WPF app?

Tags: c#, android, sql, database, send

I'm looking for tool which allow me to send "touch" from my phone to PC app. I mean, something like android app, or website, with a simple one button, and if i click it on my phone, i am able to retrieve this click in my PC app. I know I can write a simple one button app in xamarin, create database, set dependencies, write pc app connected with this db, and it will work, but maybe there is any ready solution? My target is C# WPF app on pc, but i believe it's not too important.
During research i found some Android SQL Clients, where I can connect with my database, execute queries, view tables etc. but i need just one simple button - it will be used by kids.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into RTC and you could really quickly set up a react-native app for webrtc. This only requires STUN/TURN server to 'find' one another--I'm pretty sure others also offer this service for free.